# Calabash android output to HTML gives timeout errors when finding view elements

Tags: android, xamarin.android, mvvmcross, calabash

When running calabash-android and outputting to HTML format, I am getting intermittent exceptions as per the below (typically within the first step of the app). I am using Xamarin and MVVMCross libraries.

```
Timeout waiting for elements: * marked:'Terms of Use'
(Calabash::Android::WaitHelpers::WaitError)
./features/step_definitions/calabash_steps.rb:4:in `/^User has accepted the Terms of Use$/'
features\registration.feature:8:in `Given User has accepted the Terms of Use'
2
3Given /^User has accepted the Terms of Use$/ do
4   @current_page=page(TermsOfUse).await
5   @current_page.tap_accept_button
6end
7# gem install syntax to get syntax highlighting
```

The screenshots generated show the UI element is present on the screen, and the same errors never occur when I exclude the html format option and simply write the detail out to the console. Does anybody else have any experience of this?

Comment: Please use `calabash-android console` and try to issue a query("*") command and add to your question the result of the query (or at least the relevant part)

Comment: If you can provide me the info above (the result of query("*")) I may be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the view's text has some formatting information in it.

It's a good practice to use `id` instead of `text` for identifying elements. If you have an `id`, use that:

`query("* id:'terms_of_use_id'")`

If you don't have an `id` try to add one.

---

If that is not possible try to query the whole UI with:

`query("*")`

Find the element and see what's in it's `text` property.

Comment: No problems with the query, and the text property just has plain text. As mentioned, this only seems to occur when the HTML output format parameter is set, and on looking at this further it appears to cause some inconsistency with the background steps and what happens with the app_lifecycle_hooks. For now I have resorted to using the JSON output format instead, and the same tests all run with no problems.

Comment: Meant to add, the reason I'm not using id is that I have a standard textview as a banner at the top of each of my views, and this takes on different values on each (i.e. the view title). I await the values of this textview as my view traits.